# Two Draggable Objects not working

Tags: uiimageview, touch, draggable, pong

I'm making a Pong Game based on a tutorial but the tutorial only shows you how to play against the Computer. Now I'm trying to make the two bars draggable for a Player Vs Player Game.

I tried this but this only makes both bars move at the same time.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *Drag = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
Player1.center = [Drag locationInView:self.view];

if (Player1.center.y > 533) {
    Player1.center = CGPointMake(Player1.center.x, 533);
}

if (Player1.center.y < 533) {
    Player1.center = CGPointMake(Player1.center.x, 533);
}

if (Player1.center.x < 50) {
    Player1.center = CGPointMake(50, Player1.center.y);
}

if (Player1.center.x > 270) {
    Player1.center = CGPointMake(270, Player1.center.y);
}

UITouch *Drag2 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
Player2.center = [Drag2 locationInView:self.view];

if (Player2.center.y > 20) {
    Player2.center = CGPointMake(Player2.center.x, 20);
}

if (Player2.center.y < 20) {
    Player2.center = CGPointMake(Player2.center.x, 20);
}

if (Player2.center.x < 50) {
    Player2.center = CGPointMake(50, Player2.center.y);
}

if (Player2.center.x > 270) {
    Player2.center = CGPointMake(270, Player2.center.y);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, anyone could help me but I did it. I will put the code in case of someone have the same problem. First I need to explain you need to add two Views inside the View Controller of the Game and declare them in .h file as:

```
IBOutlet UIView *zone1;
IBOutlet UIView *zone2;

    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{




    UITouch *Drag = [[event touchesForView:zone1] anyObject];
    UITouch *Drag2 = [[event touchesForView:zone2] anyObject];

    if (Drag) {


    Player1.center = [Drag locationInView:self.view];

    if (Player1.center.y > 533) {
        Player1.center = CGPointMake(Player1.center.x, 533);
    }

    if (Player1.center.y < 533) {
        Player1.center = CGPointMake(Player1.center.x, 533);
    }

    if (Player1.center.x < 50) {
        Player1.center = CGPointMake(50, Player1.center.y);
    }

    if (Player1.center.x > 270) {
        Player1.center = CGPointMake(270, Player1.center.y);
    }
}

    if (Drag2) {

    Player2.center = [Drag2 locationInView:Drag2.view];

    if (Player2.center.y > 30) {
        Player2.center = CGPointMake(Player2.center.x, 30);
    }

    if (Player2.center.y < 30) {
        Player2.center = CGPointMake(Player2.center.x, 30);
    }

    if (Player2.center.x < 50) {
        Player2.center = CGPointMake(50, Player2.center.y);
    }

    if (Player2.center.x > 270) {
        Player2.center = CGPointMake(270, Player2.center.y);
    }
    }
}
```

Remeber that the UIViews have to be a half of the View Controller, one half up, the other one half down.